# Loop mp3 crossbrowser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mp3

I have an mp3 file. It play endlessly when user opens my site.

Searching for some lighweight crossbrowser solution. It should work in IE too.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this [will](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/quick-start-guide/event-ended/) help you and it also support IE

Comment: jplayer is to big (35kb) for embedding one small mp3.

Comment: to play mp3 file in browser you need third party JS and this jPlayer is very light weighted plugin to play mp3 files

Comment: 35KB That's equal to one quite small image. ( that blue "Love Stack Overflow" image might be like 40KB. ) That one small mp3 must be like... a lot of times bigger than that 35KB. If it helps you can imagine that the mp3 is just a tad longer than it actually is.. Come on 35KB..? 35KB.. have i said it enough? ( *echo* 35KB *echo* 35KB *echo* 35KB )

Comment: @Lollero <audio> can help Steve to play this mp3 file but he also want to work with IE too

Comment: @TusharAhirrao Yes. I was speaking in behalf of using jplayer rather than against it.

Answer (score 0):

An embed tag with autostart="1" should work, cross browser.

```
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="file.mp3" height="0" width="0" autostart="1">
<noembed><bgsound src="file.mp3" ></noembed>
```

Comment: This solution isn't cross platform though is it? will only work if WMPlayer is on the client machine?